# meteor get google accesstoken after redirect

Tags: javascript, meteor, oauth, google-oauth

I'm implementing invite people in my app, I want to use googgle contacts,

If I use `accounts-google` package for authenticating the user, It will be complex process, beause I don't want to store user information,

I just want one time auth, so I'm searching for client side solutions,

```
    var url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly&client_id=5558545-3n8vg6u4nu2hm1gmuj1dbjib28p33qss.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google&response_type=token'
var newWindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=600,width=450');
```

on click of invite button I'm calling this it is working well, but how to read the `accesstoken` returned by this window.

I can't find how to do this?

I tried using `HTTP` method

```
HTTP.get(url, {}, function(e,r){
        console.log(e,r);
      });
```

but it throwing error, It is not working.

HOw to read accesstoekn from popup? or Is there any alternatives to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.hash` contains the fragment part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this.
If u need the sol let me know, cos its little long. But I did with no package and raw implementation